# Date returning asp tools?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, date, webforms

I am trying to build an asp.net web application and I am using SQL Server as my database. So right now I am in a position where I need to have a textbox(or etc.) on my screen, where the users must enter their date of birth... but one thing I require specifically is that this input(?) must return a DateTime value in the C# page. Because the code must see this date and check if this person is older than, say, 18.
First I came up with something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBoxDOB"  runat="server" TextMode="Date"/>
```

But as you can imagine; when I call this text box as: `TextBoxDOB.Text` it returns a string value and the program cannot say if this person is older than 18.

Next: I tried this `<asp:Calendar>` type of entry. But it looks too big on the web page. Perhaps I can change its appearance but I couldn't figure out what type does 'Calendar' returns.

Also after having defined that this person is old enough, I need to insert this info to my SQL Data table. In that case, assuming the data type of the DOB column is "date", will I be able to insert the user DOB to my SQL... What I actually mean; will DateTime value for this user input in C# be acceptable for SQL?

Thanks

Comment: If it returns a string you can simply parse it as a date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the text box as a date, then it will quite much produce a date value.

So, if you drop a text box on a form - set to date, then you get this:

[image]

The values will be forced (no letters or chars).

So, now the code behind the above button can do this:

```
    Dim MyDate As Date
    MyDate = TextBox2.Text

    If DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, MyDate, Date.Today) >= 18 Then
        Debug.Print("is 18 or older")
    Else
        Debug.Print("is under 18")
    End If
```

So, .net will cast from sting to date for you. I could have skipped the above variable, and even done this:

```
    If DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, Textbox2.Text, Date.Today) >= 18 Then
        Debug.Print("is 18 or older")
    Else
        Debug.Print("is under 18")
    End If
```

And the same goes if you update a database.

eg:

```
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@MyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox2.Text
```

So you can most of the time simply allow .net to "cast" the value automatic, but to be safe, one can as first example shows shove the value into a variable of date (or datetime), and use that in your code.

I should also note that the act of setting the text box to date format, then you get a free built in date pick that shows as per above.

The markup for above was this (web form designer - drag and drop).

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="261px"></asp:TextBox>
 <br />
 <br />
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="73px" />
```